# Custom ordering of terms instead of alphabetical ordering

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have created a custom post type, named products.
Inside this, there is 'internal products' and 'external products'.

[image]

This works fine, and I also have it looping through this custom post type and displaying all these results, using the code below:

```
            <div class="row">

             <?php foreach (get_terms('InternalProducts') as $cat) : ?>
             <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'InternalProducts'); ?>">
                   <?php echo "<div class='tester col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12' style='margin-bottom:30px;'>"; ?>
                   <div class="row mobilemargin" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                    <div class="categorytiletext">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopr"><img class="hovereffect img-responsive-100 newimgheight" src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>"/></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mobilewhite">
                          <div class="testdiv">
                                <h5 class="captext"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h5>

                                <p><?php if(strlen($cat->description)>$num_words = 10){
                                      echo substr($cat->description, 0, 100) . '…';
                                }
                                else {
                                      echo $cat->description;
                                }

                                ?></p>


                          </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>



              <?php echo "</div>"; ?>
        </a>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now, the issue is, this is displaying in alphabetical order, and I need to be able to choose the order, in the CMS.

If I go to Products > Internal Products, I see a list of the internal product categories, and they are also in Alphabetical order, is there a way to let the user change this?

I did look for the order button, but that doesn't exist.

IS there a way to add this maybe?

Many thanks to anyone with any useful help.
:)

Answer (score 0):

The [Intuitive Custom Order Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/intuitive-custom-post-order/installation/) works a treat, just go to settings and you can choose which options you'd like